# angular's equivalent to angularjs states

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing

In AngularJS, for routing purposes, we define states with children which makes it possible to switch between views with the result that each view is always rendered in one container:

```
$stateProvider.state("communication.create-message", {
    url: ...,
    templateUrl: ...,
    menu: ...,
    parent: "communication",
    ncyBreadcrumb: {
        label: "Create Message"
    }
});
```

Whichever state we choose - the view is always rendered within one container that has `ui-view` attribute.

I'm trying to achieve the same in **Angular 2 or above**, but I have no idea of how to reproduce the above-stated functionality.

In app.component.ts we have `router-outlet` where component templates get rendered.

Say, we have many nested child routes - is it possible to render all of them within this outlet ?

What would the code in `app-routing.module.ts` look like in this case ?

Could anyone please give a working example of how to go about it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be as follows

```
    export const ComRoute: Routes = [
{
path: 'communication-route',
children: [
{ path: 'communication', component: communicationComponent },
{ path: ':child1', component: child1Component },
{ path: ':child1/field', component: child1Component}
]
}
];
```

Comment: This is a good answer, and obviously the OP is satisfied but I'm curious if the angular router actually provides the flexibility that ui-router does. For example, the ability to change the application state via routing without changing the URL

Answer (score 4):

Step 1 : **Import Routes from @angular/router** 
in app.module.ts  .. import Routes. You have to write

```
import {Routes} from '@angular/core'
```

Step 2 : 
**Add all the routes you want to set up in an array pf type Routes like** : 
this is for informing angular all the routes in your app. Each route is a javascript object in this array.

```
const appRoutes : Routes = [
  {path : 'communication-route'} 
]
```

always you have to give path , this what you enter after your domain like "localhost :4200/communication-route".

Step 3: **Add the action to route i.e what happens when this path is reached.**

```
 const appRoutes : Routes = [
  {path : 'communication-route'} , component :communicationroutecomponent
 ]
```

here i have given the component name "communicationroutecomponent" , i.e this component  will be loaded when the path "/communication-route" is reached

Step 4:  **Register your routes in your app** 
To do this you will have to do new import in app.module.ts

```
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router'
```

Routermodule has special method forRoot() which registers our routes .

In our case we will have to write this piece of code in

```
imports :[
 RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
]
```

Our routes are now registered and angular knows our routes now.

Step 5 : **Where to display the route content i.e the html content of you route page.**

For this angular has directive .
We need to include   where we want to load our content i.e in the html.

```
<a router-outlet="/communication-route"></a>
```

**Navigating to routes :**
angular gives a directive for this routerLink
so if we want to navigate to users component , you can give this in your html element:

routerLink="/communication-route"

I hope i was able to explain how this works.

Comment: This is a good answer but I'm curious if the angular router actually provides the flexibility that ui-router does. For example, the ability to change the application state via routing without changing the URL. Having said that, I'm not convinced that such functionality is necessary per se but the abstraction is nice as you can hide the changes from the user where appropriate while still controlling the application via the router

Answer (score 1):

First of all, states are not an official AngularJS concept. They come from ui-router, which began life as an alternate to the simplistic built in router.

Eventually, ui-router became the de facto standard for routing in AngularJS while the official ng-route module was extracted into a separate, optional library by the Angular team.

ui-router, is complex but exceptional and has earned what is in my view well deserved popularity and success. This success has led to its expansion to support additional platforms enabling the same powerful state based structure in applications written for frameworks such as React.

It is now available for *Angular* (formerly known as Angular 2).

You can read the documentation and see how to get started on https://ui-router.github.io/ng2

Here is a snippet from the `src/app/app.states.ts` module of the [official example repository](https://github.com/ui-router/sample-app-angular/)

```
export const loginState = {
  parent: 'app',
  name: 'login',
  url: '/login',
  component: LoginComponent,
  resolve: [
    { token: 'returnTo', deps: [Transition], resolveFn: returnTo },
  ]
};
```

As we can see, there are compatible concepts available, including what looks like a nice evolution of the resolves API which allows function oriented injection which was generally simpler than class based injection in ui-router with *AngularJS*.

Note, I have not used it in an *Angular* project.